# How could I add rating in to the wishlist page?

Tags: layout, frontend, magento-2.1.7, wishlist

I want to add ratings into my wishlist page How could I achieve it? currently my wishlist page is looks like this

[image]

I want it to look like this

[image]

Comment: I have seen the review-module of the magento but there are 2-3 files of phtml available which file should I call & how could I fit it at my desired place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your phtml file where you want to show rating summary.

```
<div class="review-summary">

<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$_storeId = 1; // enter your store id here
$productId = 1225; // enter your product id here
$_item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

$_reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($_item, $_storeId);
$_ratingSummary = $_item->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
$_reviewCount = $_item->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
//   var_dump($_item->getRatingSummary());
?>

<?php if ((int)$_ratingSummary > 0) : ?>
    <div class="product-reviews-summary short">
        <div class="rating-summary">
            <span class="label"><span>Rating:</span></span>
            <div title="<?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%" class="rating-result">
                <span style="width:<?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%"><span><?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>
                        %</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reviews-actions">
            <a href="#" class="action view">(<?php echo $_reviewCount; ?>)</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Make sure that swatches.css is included in your page.  If it's not there , add below code in your xml file.

```
<head>
     <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
</head>
```

> Note: I do not recommend to use objectmanager directly in phtml file.
>   You should use dependency injection.

Comment: How could I use dependency injection into it?

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is not working

Comment: You don't need to add dependency in above phtml file. It will work perfectly. But it's a good practice if you create your own custom block and add all your dependencies in that block. And then call your block's function in your phtml file.

Comment: Does it throw any error ?

Comment: no it is not throwing any error but there is nothing changed with in the frontend

Comment: check if the product has rating or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67628/discussion-between-abhishek-tripathi-and-dinesh-yadav).